# DateTime Difference in time and milliseconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I need the difference of two datetime down to the millisecond comparison the first datetime is going to be less than the second, its to stop a loop in the gridviews delete event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Ok2Delete(e.RowIndex)) return;    

    // your logic goes here and the above IF statement 
    // will hopefully guarantee your code to run once.
}
private bool Ok2Delete(int ri) // ri is the record index to be deleted
{
    if (Session["ri"] == null ||
        (!((ri == ((int)Session["ri"])) &&
        (DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)Session["ri_time_stamp"]).Seconds < 2))))
    {
        Session["ri"] = ri;
        Session["ri_time_stamp"] = DateTime.Now;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

this code isn't working as expected

Comment: Your code is looking for more than a 2 second difference in the OK2Delete function.  What exactly are you looking for instead?  More than 0 milliseconds?

Comment: Also please use DateTime.UtcNow instead of DateTime.Now. It makes your app independent of machine & TimeZone.

Comment: Well everyone made an effort so i need to choose an answer but it didn't quite work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.TotalSeconds`... otherwise a TimeSpan of 122 TotalSeconds will be 2 seconds.

```
private bool Ok2Delete(int ri) // ri is the record index to be deleted
{
    if (Session["ri"] == null ||
       (!((ri == ((int)Session["ri"])) &&
       (DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)Session["ri_time_stamp"]).TotalSeconds < 2))))
    {
       Session["ri"] = ri;
       Session["ri_time_stamp"] = DateTime.Now;
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should use "TotalMilliseconds" as the question wanted time down to the millisecond.

Comment: @Sprunth, I think the OP means for the comparison to be 'accurate' to the millisecond, not the value being compared... it will be even more accurate than milliseconds.

Comment: This is some code on asp.net forums dealing with the problem of the delete event firing twice

Answer (score 2):

You will want something like this (using TotalMilliseconds of the TimeSpan that is the result of subtracting the two datetime objects):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine(dt2.Subtract(dt1).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
```

For your specific scenario:

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)Session["ri_time_stamp"]).TotalMilliseconds < 500
```

**Update**

Based on comments and review of the code, the issue is not related to time difference. Instead the problem is in the RowDeleting code. The following line:

```
if (!Ok2Delete(e.RowIndex)) return;
```

should be changed to

```
if (!Ok2Delete(e.RowIndex)) {
    e.Cancel = true; 
    return;
}
```

Comment: I think your logic may need some tweaking. Right now your logic is: if there was no previous ri in the session OR (the same ri is not in the session OR (the same ri is in the session AND the elapsed time < 2 seconds)). Is this the logic you are after?

Comment: This is some code on asp.net forums dealing with the problem of the delete event firing twice

Comment: Ah, the problem is that if it is not ok to delete, you need to set `e.Cancel = True` to prevent the deletion (in the RowDeleting event). I have updated the answer with what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

`(end - start).TotalMilliseconds`, where start and end are `DateTime`

Be aware that you may not be able to get millisecond precision out of DateTime.Now(). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143140/c-sharp-datetime-now-precision). You can use a `Stopwatch` if you need finer precision.