# How to get my time of my system in micro second?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

i want to get time of my system with accuracy of micro second in c#
How can i get this?
i can get normal time but it's not enough for me.

```
string ZamanShoru = DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Your machine is not equipped with an atomic clock, the kind of device needed to know the absolute time with microsecond precision.  Even if you had one, reading such a clock reliably is an unsolvable problem, whether your code got interrupted by the operating system is unknowable.  So the hardware isn't there, it isn't useful.  Only *incremental* time can be measured with that kind of accuracy.  Readily available in C# with the Stopwatch class.

Comment: You should consider why you need that kind of resolution...  are you really concerned about the exact time to the millisecond, or are you attempting to display time values somewhere so you can trace your code or something?

If you are trying to measure very small intervals, there's better ways to do it.  System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch may be more useful.

Comment: @HansPassant - wholeheartedly agree.  Make it an answer please? :)

Comment: It is going to be closed, Jon is very popular.

Comment: The other question is *not* a dup.  That one is about *formatting* a `DateTime` to microsecond precision - which is absolutely fine.  This question asks about getting the system time with that accuracy - which is a different question.

Comment: [This question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2143140/634824) are more relevant to this post than the suggested dup.

Comment: @HansPassant, how do you know about his hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the ["fff" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#fffSpecifier) or any number of *f* you require.

```
string ZamanShoru = DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss.ffff")
```

Comment: This shows how to *format* a DateTime with subsecond precision, which is not the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

According to the corresponding description of [DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the MSDN you can use this property to get a resolution of one hundred of a millisecond.

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, or 10 million ticks in a second.

Comment: That does *not* mean that the system clock is that accurate. Only that the `DateTime` object can store values with that precision.