# TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds is 0 when the TimeSpan is shorter than ~ 0.5ms

Tags: c#, wpf

I am implementing some diagnostics for an application where the user can see how quickly the graphics are updating and I have encountered some seemingly strange behavior. My graphic update function is called using a Timer, and it looks like this:

```
private void RefreshScreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime begin = DateTime.Now;

    // Do some updating...

    DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
    graphicsUpdateRate = (end - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

When I display the graphicsUpdateRate to a separate window later in another function, it is almost always 0. Occasionally it will actually be ~0.5, but I've never seen it below ~0.48. Is there some reason why it would clamp it to 0 if it were below this? Is there anything I'm missing when using TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds? I'm rather confused by this since it seems so random.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is just not that accurate, if you want to measure a time between a start and a end use `Stopwatch` instead.

Comment: Is it possible that when you display it you are rounding or truncating?

Comment: Possibly a duplciate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143140/c-sharp-datetime-now-precision

Comment: couldn't you just access `(end - begin).Ticks` each of these is 100 nanoseconds, which is 1e-4 milliseconds. Update: this won't work, ignore

Comment: @abc123 no, you would still get 0 ticks because the value of `.Ticks` may be returned twice for two calls very close to each other.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain lol, i didn't look at their code...which is using DateTime as a StopWatch...I was thinking about this purely from a stored datetime standpoint...woops

Comment: @abc123 I wanted the result to be displayed in Milliseconds, which is why I chose that. I suppose I could use Ticks, but then I would need to do an extra calculation that I assumed was built into TotalMilliseconds.

Comment: @RichardJones i understand what you want but 0.1 milliseconds is 0 milliseconds.  if you look at DateTime as an Object the millisecond property is `int` not a floating point

Comment: @abc123 he does not have a `DateTime` doing `(end - begin)` returns a `TimeSpan` and TimeSpan's `TotalMilliseconds` property returns a double. @Richard, you still will get 0 as a result if you use ticks. Both calls to `DateTime.Now` are returning the same `DateTime` value because `.Now` is not updated that often.

Answer (score 5):

You should be using a `StopWatch` for this.

Something like:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
// Do something.
stopwatch.Stop();
graphicsUpdateRate  = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

You could read about reasons to use `StopWatch` here:

[Is DateTime.Now the best way to measure a function's performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance)

Comment: I have nothing against Stopwatch other than the fact I had never heard of it when I implemented this. I assume it is more accurate than DateTime/TimeSpan?

Comment: @RichardJones "What time is it" and "How long does it take" are two very different questions. Don't use a tool designed for one to do the other (AKA, for measuring the time between two events it is a lot more accurate)

Comment: While correct, this answer doesn't actually address the asked question (why does it clamp).

Comment: When using a Stopwatch, the result is always 0.

Comment: @RichardJones then you likely didn't start/stop it.  Or your event is quicker than 1 millisecond.  check `Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks` to see if you are using it right.

Comment: @abc123 I'm pretty sure I used it correctly. My event is definitely quicker than 1 millisecond. And the answer used ElapsedMilliseconds, not ElapsedTicks.

Comment: @RichardJones, i merely stated that to verify that you are using it correctly please check the ElapsedTicks.  If that event is 0 then you aren't using it correctly.  Simply because Starting the stop watch then immediately topping the stop watch will not be 0. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @abc123 I am using it correctly, ElapsedTicks is returning ~150. I suppose it is too fast to record and display in Milliseconds?

Comment: @RichardJones Use the [Frequency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency(v=vs.110).aspx) property to determine how long 150 ticks is on your system with the current timer frequency.