# SSIS Populating Date Time Format: "hh mm ss nnn cc yy mm dd"

Tags: ssis

This is probably a pretty simple issue but:

I'm trying to name a file TestSheet.hhmmssnnnccyymmdd

I set up a variable in SSIS and my expression in the expression builder is set up as :

`@[User::str_Var] + 
Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("hh",getdate()),2) +
Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("mi",getdate()),2) + 
Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("ss",getdate()),2) + ".txt"`

and I know :

`Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("m",getdate()),2) +
Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("d",getdate()),2)`

Will get me "mm" and dd"

My question is.. I have "hh mm ss mm dd", how do I get "nnnccyy"?

Comment: I'm ignorant, what's nnn stand for?

Comment: nnn stands for nanoseconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you are asking for nanosecond (one billionth), I'm assuming you meant millisecond (one thousandth) precision. [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137586.aspx) only provides slicers to millisecond precision.

Using an expression, the bits to build out your format string would look like this

```
Right("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252) DatePart("hh",getdate()),2) 
+ Right("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252) DatePart("mi",getdate()),2) 
+ Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("ss",getdate()),2) 
+ Right("000" + (DT_STR,3,1252) datepart("Ms", getdate()),3) 
+ (DT_STR,4,1252) datepart("yyyy", getdate()) 
+ (DT_STR,2,1252) datepart("mm", getdate()) 
+ (DT_STR,2,1252) datepart("dd", getdate())
```

I don't know how getdate works internally but in research I did find this question [What is the best way to measure how long code takes to execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072361/what-is-the-best-way-to-measure-how-long-code-takes-to-execute/2072367) but I presume it's basically calling `DateTime.Now`  Money quotes from Eric Lippert in there but this one was most pertinent.

> Note that "wall clock time" measured by DateTime is only accurate to
>   something like 30 ms. DateTime is for representing things like a clock
>   on the wall, or the time you last edited a file; it doens't have to
>   have nanosecond accuracy, and so it does not

If you must go to nanosecond precision, happy hunting but an expression won't cut it. As @fegemo indicated, a script task can get you to one ten-millionth [custom formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) but that's still two orders of magnitude off from your desired precision.

```
this.Dts.Variables["User::CustomFormat"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmssfffffyyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: This definitely helped.  My mistake, I definitely meant millisecond I was just thinking of nano because of the n.. woops.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139875.aspx), `GetDate()` returns a date in the type `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`, which has the precision of a max of 3 fractional digits after the seconds:

> A timestamp structure that consists of year, month, day, hour, minute,
>   second, and fractional seconds. The fractional seconds have a maximum
>   scale of 3 digits.[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx)

You can use the fractional digits to determine part of the information you need:

```
DT_DBTIMESTAMP        yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff]
```

Steps:

1. Fetch the miliseconds using `DATEPART("Ms", GetDate())`
2. Divide the result by `10^6` (convert miliseconds to nanoseconds)
3. Cast the result to `DT_I4`, to get only the integer part.

Unfortunately, that would always return `000` because of the limited precision of `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`.

But, I don't know of a way to get a current date from the system with the precision that you need.