# Accurate measurement of download speed of a webclient

Tags: c#

I am using C# and the WebClient class.

This is the code I am using, inspired by another post here on SO. This code worked well for large files, it accurately displayed the download speed. However, there is now the limitation of downloading individual files, many of which are small, with small being .5-5 MB. This has caused the speed counter to skyrocket, often into the hundreds of thousands of KBps. I'm not sure what else to try to combat this. I added a second progress bar showing individual file downloads which helps improve the image a bit, but the download speed counter should really be fixed. Is there a different class to use that would solve this problem?

The WebClient in this code is disposed of properly elsewhere.
       private class NetSpeedCounter
        {
            private double[] DataPoints;

```
        private DateTime LastUpdate;
        private int NumCounts = 0;
        private int PrevBytes = 0;

        public double Speed { get; private set; }

        public NetSpeedCounter(WebClient webClient, int maxPoints = 10)
        {
            DataPoints = new double[maxPoints];

            Array.Clear(DataPoints, 0, DataPoints.Length);
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var msElapsed = DateTime.Now - LastUpdate;

                int curBytes = (int)(e.BytesReceived - PrevBytes);
                PrevBytes = (int)e.BytesReceived;

                double dataPoint = ((double)curBytes) / msElapsed.TotalSeconds;
                DataPoints[NumCounts++ % maxPoints] = dataPoint;

                Speed = DataPoints.Average();
            };
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            PrevBytes = 0;
            LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

I download the files with this code, which is started afterwards by a call to DownloadFileAsync. This code just downloads them in a chain, one after another, asynchronously.

This is setting up for starting the download
        Queue recordQ = new Queue(files);

```
    progressBar.Value = 0;
    progressBar.Maximum = recordQ.Count;

    UpdateStatusText("Downloading " + recordQ.Count + " files");

    var record = recordQ.Dequeue();
    speedUpdater.Start();
    CheckAndCreate(record.AbsolutePath);
```

Adding the event handler

```
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
    var nr = recordQ.Dequeue();
    CheckAndCreate(nr.AbsolutePath);
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        UpdateStatusText("Downloading " + recordQ.Count + " files", lblStatusR.Text);
    });
    counter.Reset();
    // download the next one
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(nr.DownloadPath, nr.AbsolutePath);
 }
 counter.Start();
 wc.DownloadFileAsync(record.DownloadPath, record.AbsolutePath);
```

This last call is what starts everything off.

Comment: How are you downloading the file? Are you using an async operation? Otherwise the DownloadProgressChanged event will not be called correctly.

Comment: @arviman I added some more information about how I download files asynchronously.

Comment: Are you initializing LastUpdate to DateTime.Now somewhere else? Not initializing it could be the issue.

Comment: @arviman Reset gets called before anything else, and I've also fixed it now by initializing it at the beginning, but there is no change

Comment: Could you also show how you're triggering your first download?

Comment: @arviman I added code showing where the first call is called, along with it's setup

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43970/discussion-between-arviman-and-tanner)

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.Now` is not accurate enough for some scenarios where timespans are recorded frequently(Eric Lippert mentions that they have a precision of 30 ms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072361/what-is-the-best-way-to-measure-how-long-code-takes-to-execute)), since DateTime.Now will return the previously used DateTime.Now when called quickly in succession. This might result in discrepencies in your speed counter due to inaccurate increases when downloads are finished very quickly. I'd recommend using `StopWatch` API for that purpose.

**EDIT**

I have created the following test Winforms application based on your code that works fine for small files. I'm getting a reasonable 200 kbps over my intranet for 5 files that are about 2MB each. Just make sure you're calling the stopwatch classes at the right places.
To replicate, create a winforms app, create 3 labels of Id *lblSpeed, lblStatus, lblFile* and copy\paste the code and rename the URI's below to the files you want to test on.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Queue<Record> recordQ;
    WebClient wc;
    NetSpeedCounter counter;
    //We store downloaded files in C:\TestDir (hardcoded in the Record class below)
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      recordQ = new Queue<Record>();
      //replace the URI string below. Nothing else to replace.
      //recordQ.Enqueue(new Record(@"URI1", "SQLtraining.exe"));
      //recordQ.Enqueue(new Record(@"URI2", "Project Mgmt.pptx"));

      //first uri to process. Second param is the file name that we store.
      Record record = new Record(@"URI0","Agile.pptx"); // replace the URI

      //Initialize a webclient and download the first record
      using (wc = new WebClient())
      {
        counter = new NetSpeedCounter(wc);
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
          if (recordQ.Count == 0)
          {
            UpdateStatusText("Done");
            return;
          }
          var nr = recordQ.Dequeue();
          //just create directory. the code uses the same directory
          CheckAndCreate(nr.Directory);
          //need not even use invoke here. Just a plain method call will suffice.
          this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
          {
              UpdateStatusText("Left to process: " + recordQ.Count + " files");
          });
          counter.Reset();
          counter.Start();
          //continue with rest of records
          wc.DownloadFileAsync(nr.DownloadPath, nr.GetFullPath());
          this.lblFile.Text = nr.DownloadPath.OriginalString;
        };
        //just update speed in UI
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
        counter.Start();
        //display URI we are downloading
        this.lblFile.Text = record.DownloadPath.OriginalString;
        //start first download
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(record.DownloadPath, record.GetFullPath());
      }

    }

    void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.lblSpeed.Text = counter.Speed.ToString();
    }
    public void UpdateStatusText(string msg)
    {
      this.lblStatus.Text = msg;
    }
    public void CheckAndCreate(string absPath)
    {
      if (!Directory.Exists(absPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(absPath);
    }   

  }
  public class NetSpeedCounter
  {
    private int NumCounts = 0;
    private int PrevBytes = 0;
    private Stopwatch stopwatch;
    public double Speed { get; private set; }
    double[] DataPoints;
    public NetSpeedCounter(WebClient webClient, int maxPoints = 10)
    {
      DataPoints = new double[maxPoints];
      stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
      Array.Clear(DataPoints, 0, DataPoints.Length);
      webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
      {
        var msElapsed = DateTime.Now - LastUpdate;

        stopwatch.Stop();
        int curBytes = (int)(e.BytesReceived - PrevBytes);
        PrevBytes = (int)e.BytesReceived;
        //record in kbps
        double dataPoint = (double)curBytes / (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds); 
        DataPoints[NumCounts++ % maxPoints] = dataPoint;
        //protect NumCount from overflow
        if (NumCounts == Int32.MaxValue)
          NumCounts = 0;

        Speed = DataPoints.Average();
        stopwatch.Start();
      };
    }

    public void Start()
    {
      stopwatch.Start();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        PrevBytes = 0;            
        stopwatch.Reset();
    }
  }
  public class Record
  {
    public string Directory;
    public string File;
    public Uri DownloadPath;
    public Record(string uriPath, string fileOutputName)
    {
      this.Directory = @"C:\TestDir\";
      this.DownloadPath = new Uri(uriPath);
      this.File = fileOutputName;
    }
    public string GetFullPath()
    {
      return this.Directory + this.File;
    }
  }  

}
```

Comment: I've updated the code to use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch, starting and restarting at appropriate times, as well as not restarting and keeping track of the elapsed time. This still does not fix the problem

Comment: Also, add the following check after you set your datapoints array since you're not doing an overflow check atm. (it won't solve the problem you're facing though)
`if (NumCounts == Int32.MaxValue)
    NumCounts = 0;`

Comment: 1) First of all, remove maxpoints, repalce double[maxpoints] with List<double>
2) Calculate not Average but Approximate

double length = (double)DataPoints.Length();
approx = (approx * length + dataPoint) * /(length + 1.0);

DataPoints.Add(dataPoint);

Example:

dataPoint sequence: 10 10 10 90 90 90
Approximate eval:  10 10 10 30 42 
(10 * 3 + 90)/4 = 30 then you can use not only f' but f'', as average of last 10 approximate values, as you do in your algorithm

Comment: @Tanner try average of last 10 for array not actual data but approx values

Comment: @arviman This has helped. It now shows accurate speeds. I also had to add a check if msElapsed == 0 set it to 1 and if e.BytesReceived > PrevBytes

Comment: @Tanner - Glad it works now. I'm not really even using msElapsed in my code (and wouldn't advise using it), but the second check seems useful in case of an overflow (which seems unlikely to happen though). While you're at it, you could do an overflow check for PrevBytes as well.

Comment: @arviman Sorry I do not use msElapsed either, it is deleted now in my code. I meant to say stopwatch.ElapsedMilleseconds. It (quite frequently) returns 0, I'm guess this has to do with the frequent starting and stopping. I tried returning if that happened, but it made the download speed show higher then it was. Setting it to 1 brought it back to what it actually was. Try outputting the bytesDifference and the ElapsedMs from the stopwatch and see if it happens to you as well

Comment: @Tanner - If you're using breakpoints, that is likely to happen since successive DownloadProgressChanged events will be called without delays, but did you try logging the ElapsedMilliseconds? If it is coming to 0, I would recommend just skipping the data point and taking the next data point where there is a difference in time. It will work as long as you don't update prevBytes when ElapsedMilliseconds is 0. Another idea is to use DateTime.Now as you did and only record data points when intervals are > than a threshold you define so you average the speed over a longer period of time.

Comment: @arviman No breakpoints, and I am logging it using System.Diagnostic.Debug. I tried not updating prevBytes and skipping if it was 0, however, e.BytesReceived reports bytes downloaded even on those degenerate cases, and ignoring it falsely inflated the speed. I will try thresholding and report back

Comment: Also the check if NumCounts == Long.MaxValue is not necessary, if the event happens once per millisecond it would take something along the lines of 200 000 years of constant running to hit the top

Comment: Actually, you were using an int so it would take 6 years of constant running to hit the top at that rate. I know it's unlikely, but it's better as a rule of thumb to make those checks.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a different way of doing it.

Instead of adding a data point for each ProgressChanged event, I now increment a counter with the amount of bytes. This counter stays across multiple files, and then I simply take a datapoint using a timer, and get the time in between using a System.Diagnostic.Stopwatch

It works very good, the accuracy is much much better, I would highly recommend doing it this way.

Here is some code

```
    class NetSpeedCounter
    {
        private Stopwatch watch;
        private long NumCounts = 0;
        private int PrevBytes = 0;
        private double[] DataPoints;

        private long CurrentBytesReceived = 0;

        public double Speed { get; private set; }

        private System.Timers.Timer ticker = new System.Timers.Timer(100);

        public NetSpeedCounter(WebClient webClient, int maxPoints = 5)
        {
            watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            DataPoints = new double[maxPoints];

            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                int curBytes = (int)(e.BytesReceived - PrevBytes);
                if (curBytes < 0)
                    curBytes = (int)e.BytesReceived;

                CurrentBytesReceived += curBytes;

                PrevBytes = (int)e.BytesReceived;
            };

            ticker.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    double dataPoint = (double)CurrentBytesReceived / watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    DataPoints[NumCounts++ % maxPoints] = dataPoint;
                    Speed = DataPoints.Average();
                    CurrentBytesReceived = 0;
                    watch.Restart();
                };
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            watch.Stop();
            ticker.Stop();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            watch.Start();
            ticker.Start();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            CurrentBytesReceived = 0;
            PrevBytes = 0;
            watch.Restart();
            ticker.Start();
        }
    }
```